# Xcode 7 Constraint Suggestion is buggy

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints, xcode7, size-classes

I made a simple screen in `Xcode 7` containing a single `UIImageView`. Then I set its constraints (as shown in the screenshot). But Xcode still suggesting to change `UIImageView's` Leading and Trailing constraints. I am not sure what is it that I am doing wrong here because this kind of error did NOT happened in Xcode 6.4[image]

Comment: The constant for the leading and trailing space is -20?

Comment: Try editing the constants and set them to 0

Comment: The -20 indicates that you have set the constraints relative to the margin. If you don't want this, edit the constraint and deselect the "relative to margin" box.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks a lot. Your suggestion worked for me. Also, is there any way I can deselect the 'Constraints to Margin' box for each view at once or  for the entire View from a single place?

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can deselect it when you create the constraint